# How can i avoid changing one variable result into a change of another

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a variable `cart` which is a list of cart items of type `CartItem`. Then a another variable `selectedItem` also of type `CartItem`. When i loop through cart and get the item of interest by comparing if its ID is equal to the ID of the selected item, I change its quantity. That works fine and expected. Challenge is it results into the selectedItem's quantity also changing. Also changing the selectedItem's quantity alone changes the quantity of the cart item. If I change both then a double increment occurs. Why is that happening and how can i prevent that. The aim is to change both. Obviously by changing only one I can get what I want but I need to understand what is going on;

```
var cart = List<CartItem>();

var selectedItem = CartItem();
```

First case

```
 for (CartItem item in cart) {
        if (item.product.id == selectedItem.product.id) {
          //this affects both selected item and item in cart's quantity
          item.quantity++;
          notifyListeners();
          printCart();
        }
      }
```

Second case

```
 for (CartItem item in cart) {
            if (item.product.id == selectedItem.product.id) {
              //this affects both selected item and item in cart's quantity
              selectedItem.quantity++;
              notifyListeners();
              printCart();
            }
          }
```

Third case

```
 for (CartItem item in cart) {
            if (item.product.id == selectedItem.product.id) {
              //this affects both selected item and item in cart's quantity
              //results in a double increment
              selectedItem.quantity++;
              item.quantity++;
              notifyListeners();
              printCart();
            }
          }
```

Comment: It's likely that these two variables reference to the same instance

Comment: @Pavel you could be right but i expected a different reference when a new instance is created

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of `CartItem()` for your `selectedCartItem` instead of referring to one of your `List<CartItem>`. You need to do something like:

```
var cart = List<CartItem>();

var selectedItem = cart[index]; // where index is the position of the selected item
```

If you don't know which one is, you can also do something like:

```
var cart = List<CartItem>();

var selectedItem = cart.singleWhere((item) => item.product.id == selectedId);
```

Comment: My intention is to create a new instance for the selectedCartItem because it is selected on an item's details page where its quantity can be decreased or increased even when it isn't in the cart.